# Stop references from objects passed as a function parameter to a new list

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I don't know how to properly write a title for this, since I don't really know what's happening.

I'm trying to get an item from an array, and add it to a new list of objects.
That works well, but whenever I modify the item (**the one at the new list**), it gets updated/modified on the original array as well...
It's like there is still some reference between the new and the original item.

That's the problem.

I'm replicating the issue here, please check the Controller's comments and run it as ***Full page***:

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('MainCtrl', function($scope){
    
    $scope.items = [
      {id: 1, name: 'item 1'},
      {id: 2, name: 'item 2'},
      {id: 3, name: 'item 3'}
    ];
    
    $scope.newItems = {
      "helo": "World!"
    };
    
    //Add the selected item object to $scope.newItems
    $scope.addItem = function(item){
      $scope.newItems.item = item;
    };
    
    //Now add a color property to the previous added object
    $scope.addColor = function(clr){
      $scope.newItems.item.color = clr;
    };
    
    //We didn't touch $scope.items so far, yet the original object gets the same
    //modifications that I do to the same object on a different objects list.
    
    
    
    //just for testing purposes
    $scope.$watch('items', function(newValue, oldValue){
        if (newValue !== oldValue) {
          $scope.showProblem = true; //this should NEVER fire
        }
    }, true);
    
  });
```

```html
<link data-require="bootstrap@3.3.5" data-semver="3.3.5" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script data-require="angularjs@1.4.9" data-semver="1.4.9" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.9/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div class="alert alert-danger" ng-if="showProblem">
      <strong>UNDESIRED BEHAVIOR:</strong> Original items array has been modified.
    </div>
    
    <ul class="list-group">
      <li ng-repeat="item in items track by item.id" class="list-group-item">
        {{item.name}}
        <a ng-click="addItem(item)" class="badge btn btn-sm btn-success" ng-if="!newItems.item">Add item</a>
        <a ng-click="addColor('red')" class="badge btn btn-sm btn-success" ng-if="newItems.item.id === item.id">Add color property</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <h3>Original item array</h3>
        <pre>{{items | json}}</pre>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <h3>New item list</h3>
        <pre>{{newItems | json}}</pre>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well - you described the problem perfectly - that's the expected behavior! Object assignments are merely references. Take the following example:

```
var obj = { color: "red" }
var obj2 = obj;

obj2.color = "black";
console.log(obj.color); //black;
```

`obj` and `obj2` both point to the same object - so updating the value of one updates the other. Angular has a built in method to handle this, `angular.copy(obj)` will create a copy of the object, without the same reference:

```
$scope.newItems.item = angular.copy(item);
```